# Why no answer tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

More often than not, the key information related to a topic of discussion is in the answers, not in the question. So why is there no option to tag based on the answers, or even separate tagging for the answers themselves? Wouldn't this also make it much easier for a questioner to discover relevant answers to their question before asking it?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128